# Entity framework - how to map this relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I have:

User:
 -ID
 -Name

Item
 -ID
 -Title

So I had things configured badly, and the good folks here at Stackover flow have pointed me right. Fantastic! Problem is, I've now realised I have an additional requirement which changes things.

In User (class) I have:
public virtual ICollection Items { get; set; }

This creates a table automatically (for the lookup) with the UserID and the ItemID.

Problem is, I want to mark some Items has Favourite (I.E if a use favourites it), Now because the table was created automatically & there's no class, I can't add a property "IsFavourite" on this class/table. So How do I go about doing this nicely?

Comment: Just making sure, but you want `user.Items` to contain a subset of the whole `Item` table, and of those items that are in `user.Items`, some (but not all) are favourited, right?

Comment: hey, yes that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

EF many-to-many relationships don't allow for extra attributes, so the easiest way to go is probably to create an explicit entity object for your link table, which you can modify as you see fit.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
}

public class UserItem
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemID")]
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'll give that a go shortly, looks great.